# CallbackURL in Auth0 not working upon successful login

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, auth0

I am having an issue with the calbbackURL in Auth0.

Here is the Auth0 service:

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';


declare var Auth0Lock: any;

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
    lock = new Auth0Lock('PRIVATE_KEY','APP_NAME-auth.auth0.com');
  private oAuthCallbackUrl:string;

    login() {
   this.lock.show((error: string, profile: Object, id_token: string) => {
     if (error) {
       console.log(error);
     }
     localStorage.setItem('profile', JSON.stringify(profile));
     localStorage.setItem('id_token', id_token);

     callbackURL: 'http://localhost:3000/app/home';
     responseType: 'code';
     authParams: {
     scope: 'openid email' }
      });
 }

 logout() {
   localStorage.removeItem('profile');
   localStorage.removeItem('id_token');
 }
}
```

This service is injected into the LoginComponent for authentication as follows:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Router, RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/router';
import {AuthHttp,AuthConfig, tokenNotExpired, AUTH_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2-jwt';

import {HomeComponent} from '../home/HomeComponent'
import {AboutComponent} from '../about/AboutComponent'
import {AuthService} from '../../services/AuthService'

declare var Auth0Lock;


/*@RouteConfig([
    {path: 'app/home', component: HomeComponent, as: 'Home'},
    {path: 'app/about', component: AboutComponent, as: 'About'},
])*/
@Component({
    selector: 'protected',
    template: '<router-outlet></router-outlet>',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    providers: [AUTH_PROVIDERS,AuthService]
})
export class LoginComponent { 

  constructor(private auth: AuthService) {
  this.auth.login();
  }

  login() {
     this.auth.login();
  }

  logout() {
    this.auth.logout();
  }

  loggedIn() {
    return tokenNotExpired();
  }

}
```

After successful login, the page is not redirected to the home page but stays at the login page

before login:
[image]

After login:
[image]